# How to resolve class ambiguity when importing libraries to classmap?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have an old library I need in my project that doesn't utilize PSR-0/4 or any namespacing at all. It has loads of PHP files with different classes. Let's say I add this library to my project via 'classmap' autoloading (as Composer documentation suggests):

```json
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "libraries/some-lib"
    ]
}
```

The problem is this library doesn't use inheritance/polymorphism - it has base classes with the same names and same methods (but different implementations of those methods) in different PHP files.

**libraries/some-lib/Foo.php:**

```php
class Foo
{
    public function bar()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**libraries/some-lib/Foo-alternate.php:**

```php
class Foo
{
    public function bar()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So when composer is generating it's classmap `Ambiguous class resolution` warnings are generated for them and only one version of `Foo` will be available to me in my project's code via `\Foo` because of name collisions.

My question is what is the way to go about this problem here **without modifying library code**? Is there any options Composer provides for situations like this so that I can import both versions of `Foo` class into composer's classmap and distinguish between the two in my project as a result?

Comment: Don't they have a `namespace` of their own?

Comment: they dont " that doesn't utilize PSR-0/4 or any namespacing at all."

Comment: This is WHY namespaces were created, to solve your problem.

Comment: wouldn't it be possible to write script which adds Namespace declarations to the files? It's quite not optimal, but at least you would get them namespaced.

Comment: @TobiasF. I am not sure how you would do that. I would have tried it by making a file, adding namespace declaration at the top and including all files by scanning each direcory using `include_once()`, `scandir()` etc

Comment: i thought of something along the lines of "for each File in this directory (recursive) add the following line after the <?php tag:" and the computed value would be something like "take the file path, cut off the part before your library directory and then create a Namespace from the Rest". This would result in something like this: a file at **/var/ww/webroot/vendor/mylib/src/client/mysql/house.php** would get a namesapce like **Mylib\Client\Mysql**.

Comment: @TobiasF. I would need to utilize filenames too as well since both files are in the same directory. So one `Foo` class in my example would be available as `SomeLib\Foo\Foo` and the other `SomeLib\FooAlternate\Foo`. But that would require writing my own script to scan every file and generate `include.php` script of some sort with such namespaces in use. I am eager to find if Composer has some elegant solution to resolve those collision on it's own.

Comment: No problem there in putting the file name itself into the Namespace. You wouldn't be required to generate a include file for all the other files, as far as i imagine it to work. When all of your files are properly namespaced, composer should be happy to load the files, but i doubt there is a buidl-in "fixing mechanism" in composer itself as you asked for.

Comment: @TobiasF. but namespacing files will modify library code and that is something I am trying to avoid (updating library would require generating those namespaces once again and that is not something very obvious for someone other than me who might be supporting this project in the future). It's a possible solution, but it has it's downsides too as you can see.

Comment: Ah, i forgot the "don't modify" part. But i don't really see a solution here other than what i suggested or another form of editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not allow two classes to have the same name, so even if you will find workaround for this (like manually loading class from specified file depending on context) this will be more like brittle hack than real solution and it will fail when you try to load these two classes in the same request.

Although you want to avoid modifying library code, this is actually the simplest and most reliable solution. It should be easy to make these changes and I doubt that library which still not uses PSR-0/4 is actively developed, so maintenance of fork should not require any additional effort.

---

> Is there any options Composer provides for situations like this so that I can import both versions of Foo class into composer's classmap and distinguish between the two in my project as a result?

Fully qualified name (which for non-namespaced classes is just class name) should be unique, this is PHP "limitation" and Composer autoloader relies on it. The best what you could get is to ignore one of these class using [`exclude-from-classmap`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#exclude-files-from-classmaps) setting:

```
"autoload": {
    "exclude-from-classmap": ["libraries/some-lib/Foo-alternate.php"]
}
```

Then Composer will autoload only class from `libraries/some-lib/Foo.php`. You may still load manually second class (`require __DIR__ . '/libraries/some-lib/Foo-alternate.php'`), but you should be really careful with this (this will result fatal error if `libraries/some-lib/Foo.php` is already loaded).

Comment: +1 for the part about the library not being active developed anymore and thus making some basic changes quite feasible, e.g. the Adding of Namespaces as I've statet in the questions comments.

Comment: @TobiasF. sadly enough the library is still actively developed (most recent update was last month). But I just wanted to see how to handle such a situation in general. In the end I decided to just fork it and fix collisions in library code manually using namespaces.